# Strong approximation in function fields

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-geometry

How does the strong approximation theorem for global function fields looks like?

For the number field $\mathbb{Q}$ it can be expressed as the surjection

$$ \mathbb{Q}^\times \times \mathbb{R}^\times \times \prod\limits_{p} \mathbb{Z}_p \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{A}^\times.$$

I want to understand the image of the adelic norm.

Comment: Could you please provide some background, or at least a link where one could learn more? I, for one, would appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970924?seq=1

Comment: @William: Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a global function field, i.e., a finite extension $\mathbb{F}_{q}(T)$, then $\left\| \cdotp \right\|_{\mathbb{A}} \twoheadrightarrow q^{\mathbb{Z}} \subset (0, \infty)$!

Comment: this is false! a good example to keep in mind (for a number field $k$; $S$ is the collection of all archimedean places) is that $\mathbb{A}_k^\times / (k^\times \prod_{v \nmid \infty} o_v^\times \prod_{v \mid \infty} k_v^\times)$ is the class group of $k$, by class field theory.

(also note that strong approximation for algebraic groups, as in Prasad's article, only applies to *simply connected semisimple* groups, and $\mathbb G_m$ isn't semisimple.)

Comment: in fact, CFT also shows for totally complex $k$ that $\mathbb{A}_k^\times / \overline{k^\times \prod_{v \mid \infty} k_v^\times}$ is the galois group of the maximal abelian extension of $k$. so density fails very badly.

Comment: thm X.2.4 in artin-tate shows that $k^\times \prod_{v \in S} k_v^\times$ is never dense in $\mathbb A_k^\times$ (the closure has infinite image).

Comment: you are welcome!